# Why doesn't this parallel merge algorithm work?

Tags: python, algorithm, merge, parallel-processing

Why doesn't this parallel merge algorithm work?

For given two sorted arrays A and B, I want to design a parallel algorithm to merge them into a sorted array C.

I wrote it with reference to the following page.

- http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/parallel-merge/229204454
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm

Essentially it is an algorithm that can be executed in parallel or sequentially. I'm trying to write a sequential merge algorithm for the time being.
How can I fix this program?

```py
#coding: utf-8

def binary_search(x, A, left, right):
    begin = left
    end = right
    while begin < end:
        middle = (begin + end) / 2
        if x <= A[middle]:
            end = middle 
        else:
            begin = middle + 1
    return end

def merge(A, B, C, R1, R2, R3):
    [[p1, r1], [p2, r2], [p3, r3]] = [R1, R2, R3]

    m = r1 - p1
    n = r2 - p2

    if m < n: # ensure thet m >= n
        A, B = B, A
        m, n = n, m
        [p1, r1], [p2, r2] = R2, R1

    if m <= 0: # both empty?
        return 

    q1 = (p1 + r1) / 2
    q2 = binary_search(A[q1], B, p2, r2)
    q3 = p3 + (q1 - p1) + (q2 - p2)
    C[q3] = A[q1]

    merge(A, B, C, [p1, q1-1], [p2, q2-1], [p3, q3])
    merge(A, B, C, [q1+1, r1], [q2, r2], [q3+1, r3])

A = [2,3,7,8,11,16]
B = [1,5,7,10,15,19]

C = [0 for i in range(len(A)+len(B))]
merge(A, B, C, [0, len(A)-1], [0, len(B)-1], [0, len(C)-1])
print C
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following statement

```
if m <= 0: # both empty?
    return
```

You are not handling the merge of 1 element arrays.

The following code works and added some comments explaining the changes. This could be a starting point.

```
#coding: utf-8
from math import ceil

def binary_search(x, A, left, right):
    begin = left
    end = right
    while begin < end:
        middle = (begin + end) / 2
        if x <= A[middle]:
            end = middle 
        else:
            begin = middle + 1
    return end

def merge(A, B, C, R1, R2, R3):
    [[p1, r1], [p2, r2], [p3, r3]] = [R1, R2, R3]

    m = r1 - p1
    n = r2 - p2

    if m < n: # ensure thet m >= n
        A, B = B, A
        m, n = n, m
        [p1, r1], [p2, r2] = R2, R1

    if m <= 0:
        # 1 elements in both the array. Merge in proper order
        if m == 0 and n == 0:
                q3 = p3
                if A[p1] < B[p1]:
                        C[q3] = A[p1]
                        C[q3+1] = B[p2]
                else:
                        C[q3] = B[p2]
                        C[q3+1] = A[p1]
        # 1 elements in A array.
        elif m == 0:
                C[p3] = A[p1]
        return

    q1 = (p1+r1)/2

    q2 = binary_search(A[q1], B, p2, r2)
    q3 = p3 + (q1 - p1) + (q2 - p2)
    C[q3] = A[q1]

    merge(A, B, C, [p1, q1-1], [p2, q2-1], [p3, q3])
    merge(A, B, C, [q1+1, r1], [q2, r2], [q3+1, r3])

A = [2,3,7,8,11,16]
B = [1,5,7,10,15,19]
print A
print B
C = [0 for i in range(len(A)+len(B))]
merge(A, B, C, [0, len(A)-1], [0, len(B)-1], [0, len(C)-1])
print C
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who's still interested (I happened to have run into the same problem with the same wiki page), the algorithm on the page seems to be incorrect. It is adapted from one in Introduction to Algorithms (a book which you can find pretty easily online). The correct implementation is here:
[Introduction to Algorithms Page 800, P-Merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KLdG.png)

Comment: Would you believe that wikipedia articles get improved just the way stack**overflow** /StackExchange posts do: by users editing them?